# Pass a variable from one method to another method in another file

Tags: typescript

In the file components.ts, I have a variable newVersion inside the method checkVersionFile().
Now in another file (version.ts), I want to retrieve this variable in another method

file: components.ts

```
public checkVersionFile(): any {
        const contentVersion = fs.readFileSync(this.tmpDir + "/components/Version", 'utf8')
        if(contentVersion.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')){
            let match = /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)-(\d+)-(SNAPSHOT)$/.exec(contentVersion);
            const newVersion =  (parseInt(match[1])) + '.' + (parseInt(match[2])) + '.' + (parseInt(match[3])) + '-' + (parseInt(match[4]));
            logger.info("Version: "+newVersion);      
        }
        else {
            logger.error("error"); 
        }
    }
```

file version.ts

```
public async retrieveVersion(): {
        let searchVersionsUri = config.jiraApiUri + 'project/versions';       
        const jsonResp = await this.jiraClient.get(searchVersionsUri);
        const version: any = jsonResp.find(version => {
            return version.name == newVersion  // here want retrieve variable

        });
        return new ReleaseVersion(version.id, version.name, version.released);
    }
```

Comment: just export your const in the components.ts and import into version.ts

Comment: Ok i'm tring to do this but can I do export const newVersion = .... ? @Akash

Comment: nope, you can not export an const from within the function but you can declare that const outside your function "export const newVersion"  . set the value of this const from within the checkVersionFile() function and can import this const in the file where you have retrieveVersion() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can **directly** `export` a variable inside a function. Instead you can make function `checkVersionFile` return the value of `newVersion` and `export` the method, then `import` it. In `version.ts`, with `checkVersionFile()` you can get value of `newVersion`.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your compilation settings. If you compile all your `.ts` files into one `.js` file it should already work. Or do you want to use modules?

TSCONFIG.JSON

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outFile": "docs/js/main.js"
    },
    "include": [
        "dev/**/*"
    ]

}
```

Comment: Compile all file

Comment: If all `.ts` files are compiled into one `.js` file you can just call the functions directly.